# parsing array of objects to array of string elements in swift JSON object

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to parse the JSON object received from Web service which gives the result as JSON object of status and data.data again is a array of objects, from this object I want to take one element on the basis of which I have to fill a tableview.

web Service results comes as

```
{"status":1,"data":[{"service_id":"1","service_name":"Painter"},{"service_id":"2","service_name":"Plumber"},{"service_id":"3","service_name":"Electrician"},{"service_id":"4","service_name":"Handyman"},{"service_id":"5","service_name":"Carpenter"},{"service_id":"6","service_name":"Mason"}]}
```

parsing in swift I did as:--
created one class

```
class ABC: NSObject {   

    var service_name:String?
    var service_id : Int?

    init(service_name:String,service_id:Int) {
        self.service_name = service_name
        self.service_id = service_id

    }


        let myUrl = URL(string: "services.php");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json
                {
                    let status=parseJSON["status"] as? Int

                    let newdata : NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                    self.model=(newdata.value(forKey: "data") as? [ABC])!
```

My problem is I am getting an array of objects in self.model as service_name and service_id keys.Now I want to take out one array of strings that contains all the service_name object values.Its saying not able to convert NSArray to swift array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by others use `(De)codable`. It's easy to use and very comfortable. No type cast and no literal keys.

Create two structs, declare the members as non-optional constants with *camelCased* names and omit the initializer.

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let status : Int
    let data : [Service]
}

struct Service : Decodable {
    let serviceName : String
    let serviceId : String
}
```

Then decode the JSON in another class or struct

```
    let myUrl = URL(string: "services.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        if let error = error { print(error); return }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let json = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data!)
            let status = json.status
            let newdata = json.data
        } catch { print(error))
    }
    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use native Swift type `Dictionary` everywhere you use `NSDictionary` now

Then get certain value for key by specifing key in dictionary's subscript

```
if let model = newData["data"] as? [ABC] {
    self.model = model
}
```

---

Anyway, I would suggest you to start using `Codable` instead of `JSONSerialization`

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let status: Int
    let data: [ABC]
}
struct ABC: Decodable {
    let serviceName: String
    let serviceId: String // note that `serviceId` isn’t `Int` But `String`
}
```

and then decode your data using `JSONDecoder`

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
do {
    let response = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data!)
    self.model = response.data
} catch { print(error) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to drop `JSONSerialization` and use `Codable` protocol instead with `CodingKeys`.

Here is a simple example to see how it works.

```
struct Service : Codable {
    let id : Int
    let name : String

    // keys
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "service_id"
        case name = "service_name"
    }
}

...
// assuming our data comes from server side
let jsonString = "..."
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let user = try jsonDecoder.decode(Service.self, from: jsonData)
    print("Getting service: \(service.id) \(service.name)")
} catch {
    print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
}
```

More [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) here.